# How to skip one or more elements in a loop on a condition?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a simple while loop. I want to skip by one no. when a condition is true. It works fine when I want to check one no only. When I want to check for two successive numbers, it does not completely work.
here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
import time
import pyautogui
import keyboard
def do():

    image = pyautogui.screenshot()


    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image),cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    return image
n=ls[0]
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        n+=1
        if os.path.exists('im'+str(n)+'.png')==True:# it is this part
            n+=1
        time.sleep(3)
        cv2.imwrite("im"+str(n)+".png", do())
```

now for example, if im5.png and im6.png are present, it works for the former and not for the latter.
*Any help will be greatly appreciated*

Comment: `if condition: continue` And BTW how do you plan to ever leave the loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "check for two successive numbers"? Please give an example.

Comment: @Klaus D. i hv another part of my code which is unnescessary to give here. on pressing 'q' i will leave the loop and on pressing 'e' i will kill pythonw.exe

Comment: @DYZ see at the end of my post i wrote two lines

Comment: What value does `ls[0]` hold?

Comment: @Linux Geek oh it is 0. to prevent errors, after the loop is broken, the last value of n is stored in the list and the previous value is deleted, so that the loop may start from there next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `continue` after `n+=1`

```
 if os.exists('im'+str(n)+'.png')==True:
    n+=1
    continue #this line
```

But still, there's one more problem, even after adding this, your loop is going to run forever, there's no `break` condition

Comment: i know. i have not given the rest of my code; on pressing 'q' the loop will break and on pressing 'e' it will kill pythonw.exe

Comment: @PsychopathicAzula ohh, I see.